# making HTML Source input the default in tinyMCE

Tags: tinymce

Im applying tinyMCE to a text area where I expect only video embed codes to be pasted. Since this works only if the embed code is pasted into the HTML dialog box(theme_advanced_button: "code"), I was wondering if i could make tinyMCE take HTML input by default in the text area.

Is it possible to do this? If so, how?

Thanks!

Comment: this depends on the way you want to enter the content